# Is a let variable equal to a var variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have something like:

```
let x = 20;
var z = 20;
```

will

```
x === z
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it out and see for yourself...

(If nothing is displayed that is because you are [using a browser that doesn't support `let`](http://caniuse.com/#search=let).)

```js
"use strict";

let x = 20;
var z = 20;

document.write(x === z);
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2039244) for details about the differences between `let` and `var`:

> The difference is scoping. `var` is scoped to the nearest function block (or global if outside a function block), and `let` is scoped to the nearest enclosing block (or global if outside any block), which can be smaller than a function block.

Answer (score 6):

`===` does not compare variables - it does compare values. Given that both your variables hold the same value (`20`), they will be "equal".

It does not matter for the equality [how those variables were declared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1048572), only that both of them are in scope and have that value assigned when the `===` operation is evaluated. Which is the case in your example snippet.